# How to implement process execution as reactive `Observable[String]

Tags: scala, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, monix

I want represent external process execution as `Observable[String]`, where `String` - line from process output. Here example what I do, it's worked:

```
import monix.eval.Task
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
import monix.reactive.Observable

object TestSo {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val lineStream = scala.sys.process.Process("python3 test.py").lineStream

    val lineStreamO: Observable[String] = Observable.fromIterator(Task(lineStream.iterator))
      .doOnNext(l => Task(println(l))) //logging
      .guarantee(Task(println("clean resources")))

    println(lineStreamO.toListL.runSyncUnsafe())
  }

}
```

You can see, that process emits new line every second. But it does not matter. Just provide full example, `test.py`:

```
from time import sleep
print(0, flush=True)
sleep(1)
print(1, flush=True)
sleep(1)
print(2, flush=True)
sleep(1)
print(3, flush=True)
sleep(1)
print(4, flush=True)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
clean resources
List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

**Problem**:

I want to have timeout - if process freezes (for example `sleep 100000`) process should be killed after timeout. Also if process compelted or fail, some resources should be cleaned (`guarantee` in example). NonZero exit code should represent failure.

How to implement process execution as `Observable[String]` with propper error handling? `rx-java` solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The need of a timeout will force you to re-write a major part of the `lineStream` logic. On the other hand with such a re-write you can avoid an intermediate `Iterator` and directly push lines into a `Subject`. For the timeout logic you can use Monix `timeoutOnSlowUpstream` method but you still have to handle the timeout error and close the started process.

Also there is a choice on what to do with long output and several subscribers. In this code I decided to use a limited buffer of `replayLimited`. Depending on your needs you might choose some different strategy. Here is a sketch of a solution:

```
object ProcessHelper {

  import scala.sys.process.{Process, BasicIO}
  import scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration
  import monix.eval.Task
  import monix.execution.Scheduler
  import monix.reactive.subjects.ConcurrentSubject
  import monix.reactive.Observable

  private class FinishedFlagWrapper(var finished: Boolean = false)

  def buildProcessLinesObservable(cmd: String, timeout: FiniteDuration, bufferLines: Int = 100)(implicit scheduler: Scheduler): Observable[String] = {
    // works both as a holder for a mutable boolean var and as a synchronization lock
    // that is required to preserve semantics of a Subject, particularly
    // that onNext is never called after onError or onComplete
    val finished = new FinishedFlagWrapper()

    // whether you want here replayLimited or some other logic depends on your needs
    val subj = ConcurrentSubject.replayLimited[String](bufferLines)

    val proc = Process(cmd).run(BasicIO(withIn = false,
      line => finished.synchronized {
        if (!finished.finished)
          subj.onNext(line)
      }, None))

    // unfortunately we have to block a whole thread just to wait for the exit code
    val exitThread = new Thread(() => {
      try {
        val exitCode = proc.exitValue()
        finished.synchronized {
          if (!finished.finished) {
            finished.finished = true
            if (exitCode != 0) {
              subj.onError(new RuntimeException(s"Process '$cmd' has exited with $exitCode."))
            }
            else {
              subj.onComplete()
            }
          }
        }
      }
      catch {
        // ignore when this is a result of our timeout
        case e: InterruptedException => if(!finished.finished) e.printStackTrace()
      }
    }, "Process-exit-wait")
    exitThread.start()

    subj.timeoutOnSlowUpstream(timeout)
      .guarantee(Task(finished.synchronized {
        if (!finished.finished) {
          finished.finished = true
          proc.destroy()
          exitThread.interrupt()
        }
      }))
  }
}
```

Usage example would be something like:

```
def test(): Unit = {
  import monix.execution.Ack._
  import monix.reactive._
  import scala.concurrent._
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global


  val linesO = ProcessHelper.buildProcessLinesObservable("python3 test.py", 5 seconds, 2) // buffer is reduced to just 2 lines just for this example 

  linesO.subscribe(new Observer[String] {
    override def onNext(s: String): Future[Ack] = {
      println(s"Received '$s'")
      Future.successful(Continue)
    }

    override def onError(ex: Throwable): Unit = println(s"Error '$ex'")

    override def onComplete(): Unit = println("Complete")
  })

  try {
    println(linesO.toListL.runSyncUnsafe())
    println(linesO.toListL.runSyncUnsafe()) // second run will show only last 2 values because of the reduced buffer size
    println("Finish success")
  }
  catch {
    case e: Throwable => println("Failed with " + e)
  }
}
```

Comment: In case of `while(True): sleep 1` and timeout bigger than 1, process never ends. Any hints how to implement "summary" timeout?

Comment: @zella, sorry, I'm not sure I get you. For me `while(True): sleep(1)` works as expected i.e. stops by timeout. Did you mean `while(True): print(something) sleep(1)`? Well in this case I see a fundamental conflict in your requirements. Still if this is what you want for some reason, you can just create an `Observable.evalDelayed`, subscribe to it and do the same stuff I do when `exitCode != 0` i.e. assign `finished.finished = true` and do `subj.onError` with some exception.

Comment: `subj.takeUntil(Observable.fromTask(Task.sleep(timeout)))` worked for me. Thanks, I have learned a lot of new things today.

Comment: @zella, note that there is a subtle but potentially important difference between `takeUntil` and what I suggested. Particularly `takeUntil` will end with successful `onComplete` while my approach will generate `onError` which is IMHO a more appropriate for a timeout. Still `onComplete` might be what you want in your particular use case.

Comment: Seems like `subj.takeUntil(Observable.evalDelayed(timeout, throw new TimeoutException))` worked.

Comment: @zella, yes, that will probably work. `takeUntil` passes the same exception to the main `Observable`

Answer (score 0):

I implemened process execution as reactive `rxjava2` `Observable` in small [library](https://github.com/zella/rx-process2), that wraps [NuProcess](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/NuProcess) in reactive way. For example:

```
PreparedStreams streams = builder.asStdInOut();

Single<NuProcess> started = streams.started();
Single<Exit> done = streams.waitDone();
Observable<byte[]> stdout = streams.stdOut();
Observer<byte[]> stdin = streams.stdIn();

done.subscribe();
```